# PL/SQL Can't grant privileges while logged as system

Tags: oracle, permissions

I can't grant the execute privilege on `DBMS_LOB` (I need it to operate on files), even when I'm logged as *system*. What can I do? Granting `DBA ROLE` doesn't help at all.

```
Error starting at line 7 in command:
grant execute on sys.DBMS_LOB TO PGADMIN
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01031:
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
```

I've been racking my brain about it for few hours. I hope someone can provide a solution that will work in my case.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full text of the actual command issued.

Answer (score 4):

> SYSTEM is a typical database user (such as HR or OE)

The `DBMS_LOB` package belongs to `SYS` schema so that only the owner(Or user having the `GRANT OPTION`) can grant the object privilieges to other users. So if you connect as `SYSDBA` using `SYSTEM` user you will be connected to `SYS` schema.

```
SQL> conn system/oracle
Connected.
SQL> show user
USER is "SYSTEM"
SQL> 

SQL> grant execute on dbms_lob to hr;
grant execute on dbms_lob to hr
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges


SQL> conn system/oracle as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> 
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> grant execute on dbms_lob to hr;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> revoke execute on dbms_lob from hr;

Revoke succeeded.
```

**OR**

You can grant `EXECUTE` on `DBMS_LOB` to `SYSTEM` user with `GRANT OPTION` then user `SYSTEM` user to grant that object privilege to other users.

```
SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> grant execute on dbms_lob to system with grant option;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn system/oracle
Connected.
SQL> grant execute on dbms_lob to hr;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```